# Error: "Cannot return a void result" in Java recursive list reverse method

Tags: java, recursion, return, void, signature

So, I have some weird problems with a method I am writing in Java, and I could use some help. This is the code:

```
    public <T> LinkedList<T> recursiveReverse(LinkedList<T> l){
        if(l.size() == 1) return l;
        else{
            T a = l.pop();
            return recursiveReverse(l).addLast(a); <-- Error
            }
       }
```

I've done some searching on this problem, but all I've got was when people tried to return things when their signature was void. I don't feel like there is anything wrong with this code, and that Java is being a bum. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method [addLast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addLast(E)) returns *void* whereas the return type of `recursiveReverse`  is a `LinkedList<T>`, rather what you want is:

```
recursiveReverse(l).addLast(a);
return l;
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know what I was thinking when I was doing this. I knew addLast was void, but I didn't make the connection. Thanks!